# How can I run JUnit tests under SCons?

Tags: junit, scons

Seems like there's no answer on the internets. All I need is to concoct an SConstruct that does two things:

- runs JUnit
- produces reasonable output for CruiseControl to display

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer.
First, you can of course run junit as a command-line from under scons, something like this:

```
java -cp $LIB:target/test-classes/:target/classes org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.mycompany.MyTestSuite
```

but there's no way you can produce an xml output for CruiseControl: xml is produced by either ant or maven. All you'll have is a raw text which you can of course intercept and parse in your python (scons) script.

Not exactly a solution.